# jQuery slick slider with multiple rows with asNavFor not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

To create a standard e-commerce slideshow template I would like to have two sliders with two asNavFor parameters values for slider to slider.

Link to [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/jackblackjack/pen/XWMExgR)

As Code:

```
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-for">
      <div><h3>1</h3></div>
      <div><h3>2</h3></div>
      <div><h3>3</h3></div>
      <div><h3>4</h3></div>
      <div><h3>5</h3></div>
      <div><h3>6</h3></div>
      <div><h3>7</h3></div>
      <div><h3>8</h3></div>
      <div><h3>9</h3></div>
      <div><h3>10</h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-nav">
      <div><h3>1</h3></div>
      <div><h3>2</h3></div>
      <div><h3>3</h3></div>
      <div><h3>4</h3></div>
      <div><h3>5</h3></div>
      <div><h3>6</h3></div>
      <div><h3>7</h3></div>
      <div><h3>8</h3></div>
      <div><h3>9</h3></div>
      <div><h3>10</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

With CSS:

```
body {
  background: gray;
}
.slider {
  font-family:Arial;
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.slider h3 {
    background: #fff;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.slider .action{
  display:block;
  margin:100px auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.slider .action a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px; 
  background:#f30;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.slider .action a:hover{
  background:#000;
}
```

and JS:

```
   $('.slider-for').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed:9000,
    speed:700,
    mobileFirst: true,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    rows: 1,
    fade: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    infinite: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    pauseOnHover:false,
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    respondTo:'min',
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    cssEase:'linear'
  });

  $('.slider-nav').slick({
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed:9000,
    speed:700,
    mobileFirst: true,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    rows: 2,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    infinite: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    pauseOnHover:false,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    respondTo:'min',
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    cssEase:'linear'
});
```

And slider with one row change slide in slider with two rows but when you click for any slide in slider with two rows you won't get the slide number you clicked on.

Works as wanted when $('.slider-nav') there is only one row, you can change rows: 2 to rows: 1 to $('.slider-nav').

How to get the same slide for `$('.slider-for')` when you click on it in `$('.slider-nav')`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a common issue with Slick Slider: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1206

I was looking to do the same thing and I think I found a solution with some help from that github link

https://jsfiddle.net/sn3b5pcu/

```
  $('.slider-for').slick({
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed:9000,
speed:700,
mobileFirst: true,
slidesToScroll: 1,
slidesToShow: 1,
rows: 1,
fade: true,
swipeToSlide: true,
infinite: false,
focusOnSelect: true,
pauseOnHover:false,
arrows: true,
dots: false,
respondTo:'min',
asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
cssEase:'linear'
});
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
autoplay: false,
autoplaySpeed:9000,
speed:700,
mobileFirst: true,
slidesToScroll: 1,
slidesToShow: 4,
rows: 2,
swipeToSlide: true,
infinite: false,
focusOnSelect: true,
pauseOnHover:false,
arrows: false,
dots: false,
respondTo:'min',
asNavFor: '.slider-for',
cssEase:'linear'
});
$('.slick').slick();
var $parent = $(".slider-for");
var $nav = $(".slider-nav");
var $content = $nav.find("div");
var killit = false;
$content.on("click", function(e){
if( !killit ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var idx = $(this).data("thumb");
    $parent.slick("goTo", idx-1);
}
});
$nav
.on("beforeChange", function() {
    killit = true;
}).on("afterChange", function() {
    killit = false;
});
```